# Correct way to initialize a React Native Component with Navigation

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm currently struggeling using React native navigation and class components.
Before I had no extra options in the StackNavigator and just the `<MainStack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />;`, that worked fine.

Now I want to pass the dataservice so I can pass a mocked implementation of the interface for tests. However this throws me type errors regarding the navigation object and I cant figure out how to pass both.

The class component:

```
interface IHomeScreenState {
 ...
//Some data
}

interface IHomeScreenProps {
  navigation: NavigationStackProp<{userId: string}>;
  //navigation: any;
  dataService: IDataService;
}

// eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier
export class HomeScreen extends React.Component<
  IHomeScreenProps,
  IHomeScreenState
> {
  constructor(props: IHomeScreenProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    //...
    };
  }
}
```

My stack navigation:

```
export const MainScreenStack = ({navigation}: any) => {
  return (
    <MainStack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
      <MainStack.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{navigation: navigation, dataService: new DataService()}}
      />
    </MainStack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

I get the following error in the `options={{navigation: navigation, dataService: new DataService()}}` line:

> Type '{ navigation: any; dataService: DataService; }' is not assignable to type 'NativeStackNavigationOptions | ((props: { route: RouteProp<MainStackParams, "HomeScreen">; navigation: any; }) => NativeStackNavigationOptions) | undefined'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'navigation' does not exist in type 'NativeStackNavigationOptions | ((props: { route: RouteProp<MainStackParams, "HomeScreen">; navigation: any; }) => NativeStackNavigationOptions)'.ts(2322)

Comment: will passing data service into [initialParams](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params#initial-params) work for you ?

Comment: Took me some fiddling but it should do the trick, thanks for tipping me in that direction.